# Why do ZSH parameter expansion flag(s) not work with here-strings?

Tags: zsh

The `u` parameter expansion flag is supposed to output only unique array values. And it does ... sometimes.

```
$ stuff=(a b a c)
$ echo ${(u)stuff}
a b c
$ cat <<< ${(u)stuff}
a b a c
```

What gives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `echo ${(u)stuff}`, `echo` is passed the 3 unique elements of the array (empty ones elided). You're in list context, for the arguments to a simple command.

```
$ printf '"%s"\n' ${(u)stuff}
"a"
"b"
"c"
```

But after `<<<` it's a non-list context, `cat` has only one stdin, `<<<` takes only one thing to store in the temporary file that will make up `cat`'s stdin, so the elements of the array are joined with the first character of `$IFS`. Same as in:

```
echo "$stuff"
scalar=$stuff
[[ $stuff = x ]]
case $stuff... in
...
```

All cases where only one argument is expected and more would not make sense.

Here, it's enough to do:

```
cat <<< ${${(u)stuff}}
```

For the `u` flag to be applied first and the joining to happen at the outer level.

Same in:

```
scalar=${${(u)stuff}}
```

You'd however need:

```
$ printf '"%s"\n' "${${(@u)stuff}}"
"a b c"
```

To force list context for the inner expansion, and do IFS-joining in the outer one, for one argument to be passed to `printf`.

Rather than relying on a global parameter such as `$IFS`, you may want to explicitly specify how the array elements should be joined:

```
printf '"%s"\n' ${(j[ ])${(u)stuff}}
```

```
cat <<< ${(j[ ])${(u)stuff}}
```

See the [Expansion *Rules*](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Rules) for details.